# creating sub-lists from list of strings containing given number of words maximum

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.8

I have a list of strings. I want to create sub-lists from the list such that it contains strings from the original list, but such that the number of words in each sub-list should be less than 16 and the preceding string should be the first element of the sub-list, except for the first sublist.

To give an example,  let us say my list is the below one, containing 5 strings with each string containing varying number of words.

```
qq = ['blended e learning forumin planning', 'difficulties of learning as forigen language', 'difficulties of grammar', 'students difficulties in grammar', 'difficulties of english grammar']
```

I want to create sub-lists satisfying the above condition with maximum of 16 words and each list containing preceding string as the first element (except first sub-list). There will be only two sub-lists and my output will be

```
q1 = ['blended e learning forumin planning', 'difficulties of learning as forigen language', 'difficulties of grammar']
q2 = ['difficulties of grammar', 'students difficulties in grammar', 'difficulties of english grammar']
```

This is what I have tried. Is it correct and is there any better way to do it ? I got millions of lists to do this operation.

```
qq = ['blended e learning forumin planning', 'difficulties of learning as forigen language', 'difficulties of grammar', 'students difficulties in grammar', 'difficulties of english grammar']

psz = 0
pi = 0
msz = 16
subqq = list()
qq_i = list()

for i in range(len(qq)):
    csz=psz+len(qq[i].split())
    if (csz>msz):
        subqq.append(qq_i.copy())
        qq_i.clear()
        qq_i.append(qq[i-1])
        qq_i.append(qq[i])
        psz = 0
    else:
        qq_i.append(qq[i])
        psz += len(qq[i].split())

subqq.append(qq_i)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Phydeaux I added my code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with. It is a similar algorithm to yours and the answer by SorousH Bakhtiary, but should be free of the word count error and I think it is easier to read.

It also raises an error in the case where we start a new sublist with the last phrase in the previous one and cannot add the next phrase without breaking the word limit. This could happen if there are two consecutive phrases that have >8 words - if you can be sure that never happens then you can omit that part.

```
def count_words(phrase):
    return len(phrase.split())


def sublists_with_max_words(main_list, max_words=16):
    output_sublists = []

    current_sublist = []
    current_sublist_words = 0

    for phrase in main_list:
        words_in_phrase = count_words(phrase)

        if (current_sublist_words + words_in_phrase) > max_words:
            # If we cannot add the phrase to the sublist without breaking
            # the word limit, then add the sublist to the output
            output_sublists.append(current_sublist)

            # Start a new sublist with the last phrase we added
            last_phrase = current_sublist[-1]
            current_sublist = [last_phrase]
            current_sublist_words = count_words(last_phrase)

            # If we cannot add the phrase to the new sublist either, then raise
            # an exception as we cannot continue without breaking the word limit
            if (current_sublist_words + words_in_phrase) > max_words:
                raise ValueError(
                    f"Cannot add '{phrase}' ({words_in_phrase} words) to a new"
                    f" sublist with {current_sublist_words} words"
                )

        # Add the current phrase to the sublist
        current_sublist.append(phrase)
        current_sublist_words += words_in_phrase

    # At the end of the loop, add the working sublist to the output
    output_sublists.append(current_sublist)

    return output_sublists


print(sublists_with_max_words(qq))
```

Answer (score 1):

Mine is similar to yours and the algorithm is mostly the same, but I believe this should run slightly faster:

```
def fn(lst, n):
    word_count = 0
    res = []
    temp_lst = []

    for item in lst:
        len_current_item = len(item.split())
        word_count += len_current_item

        if word_count < n:
            temp_lst.append(item)

        else:
            res.append(temp_lst)
            last_item = res[-1][-1]
            temp_lst = [last_item, item]
            word_count = len_current_item + len(last_item.split())

    res.append(temp_lst)

    # Checking for last item's lenght as Phydeaux pointed out in comments.
    if word_count > n:
        res.append([temp_lst.pop()])

    return res
```

output :

```
['blended e learning forumin planning', 'difficulties of learning as forigen language', 'difficulties of grammar']
['difficulties of grammar', 'students difficulties in grammar', 'difficulties of english grammar']
```

I tried to avoid copying and clearing, and a lit bit of small changes.

Comment: This is similar to what I came up with, but FYI `word_count = len(item.split())` doesn't account for the words in `res[-1][-1]`

Comment: Also it is worth considering what happens when there are two consecutive items that have >8 words - in this case it is impossible to include the previous item in the new list and not break the word limit. Not sure what OP wants to happen in that case

Comment: @Phydeaux Could you elaborate your first comment a bit more ? Are you pointing to the last iteration that `res[-1][-1]` is not taking to the account?

Comment: You set the word count to be the word count of the current item only, but the sublist has two items in it

Comment: @Phydeaux Thanks You're right this should be fixed by now.

Answer (score 1):

Since others have already provided valid solutions, here's another interesting approach implemented through a **mapping scheme** between each `qq` element and the respective cumulative number of words.

First off create the mapping dict:

```
qq_map = {q: len(" ".join(qq[:n+1]).split()) for n, q in enumerate(qq)}

# {'blended e learning forumin planning': 5, 'difficulties of learning as forigen language': 11,
# 'difficulties of grammar': 14, 'students difficulties in grammar': 18,
# 'difficulties of english grammar': 22}
```

Then you build the grouped list with the mapping information:

```
qq = [[q for q in qq if qq_map[q] in range(i*16, (i+1)*16)] /
     for i in range(-(-qq_map[qq[-1]] // 16))]

# [['blended e learning forumin planning', 'difficulties of learning as forigen language', 'difficulties of grammar'], 
# ['students difficulties in grammar', 'difficulties of english grammar']]
```

> Note: `-(-qq_map[qq[-1]] // 16)` is an equivalent to `math.ceil(qq[-1] / 16)`. You can
> replace it if you'd like a more concise and less 'arithmetic'
> expression.

Finally you process the list again in order to push the last string of each group in the following one (except the very first of course):

```
qq = [[qq[i-1][-1]] + qq[i] if i != 0 else qq[i] for i in range(len(qq))]

# [['blended e learning forumin planning', 'difficulties of learning as forigen language', 'difficulties of grammar'], 
# ['difficulties of grammar', 'students difficulties in grammar', 'difficulties of english grammar']]
```